# Почему вылетает консольное приложение на C в Code::Blocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Имеется следующий код на C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define Te 52.0
#define Ts 2196.0
#define Tc 2196.0
#define Traw_max 246140.0
#define RL 7

const int W[] = {16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024};
double mod = 0.0;

double lambda(int N, double Traw);
int round_p(double x);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    fp = fopen("D:\\data_a.txt", "w");
    for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {printf("%d\n", i); fprintf(fp, "%d %.9f\n", i, lambda(1, Traw_max / i));}
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

double lambda(int N, double Traw)
{
    if(Traw < Ts) return 0.0;
    if(N <= 0) return 0.0;
        printf("mark0\n");
        int t = 0, i, j;
        int max_t = round_p(Traw / Te) + 1;
        printf("%d\n", max_t);
        double *Pold[W[0]], *Pnew[W[0]], lambda = 0.0;
        printf("mark0.5\n");
        for(i = 0; i < W[0]; i++)
        {
            Pold[i] = calloc(max_t, sizeof(double));
            Pnew[i] = calloc(max_t, sizeof(double));
        }
        printf("mark0.7\n");
        for(i = 0; i < W[0]; i++) {printf("%d\n", i); Pold[i][0] = 1.0 / W[0]; printf("%e\n", Pold[i][0]);}
        printf("mark1\n");
        while(t < max_t)
        {
            for(i = 1; i < W[0]; i++) for(j = 0; j < max_t; j++) Pnew[i - 1][j] = Pold[i][j];
            for(j = 0; j < max_t; j++) for(i = 0; i < W[0]; i++) Pnew[i][j + 1] = Pold[0][j] * (1.0 / W[0]);
            for(i = 0; i < W[0]; i++) for(j = 0; j < max_t; j++) Pold[i][j] = Pnew[i][j];
            for(i = 0; i < W[0]; i++) for(j = 0; j < max_t; j++) if((t + 1 - j >= 0) && (j * Ts + (t + 1 - j) * Te > Traw - Ts) && (j * Ts + (t + 1 - j) * Te <= Traw))
            {
                lambda += j * Pold[i][j];
                Pold[i][j] = 0.0;
            }
            t++;
        }
        printf("mark2\n");
        for(i = 0; i < W[0]; i++)
        {
            free(Pold[i]);
            free(Pnew[i]);
        }
        return lambda;
}

int round_p(double x)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= x; i++);
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

Который успешно компилируется. Однако при попытке запуска программа вылетает. В диспетчере задач всё нормально - процесс съедает стандартные 25% процессорного времени, памяти ест мало. В некоторых местах в коде я расставил метки консольного вывода, и заметил два наиболее частых случая:

1. Функция `lambda` вызывается один раз, доходит до метки *mark2* и программа вылетает.
2. Функция `lambda` вызывается ровно 61 раз (число зверя, не иначе), и программа вылетает при попытке присвоения в цикле элемента массива `Pold[0][0]`. Если предварительно попытаться присвоить значение элементу массива вне цикла, то также происходит вылет.

В чем дело? Что надо сделать чтобы понять причину ошибки?

Comment: Я думаю, что мало кому будет интересно разбираться в этом бессмысленном коде.

Comment: Можно просто указать возможные причины. Память освобождается, в файл раньше всегда писалось. Что ещё мне нужно проверить?

Comment: Функцию `round_p(double x)` я взял на заметку. Давно так не смеялся. А по факту хочу сказать, что никак не пойму, зачем вы вызываете `calloc` и `free`. Второе, не мешало бы конструкцию обернуть в `try catch` и тогда станет ясно в чем дело

Comment: @hunter Чтобы указать, что где-то не освобождается память, нужно исследовать этот код. А это занятие не для слабонервных.

Comment: @ArchDemon Насколько мне известно, в C нет конструкций try/catch.

Comment: Исключения не вылетают. Если бы они вылетали бы, это должно было быть видно в консоли. И, если честно, впервые слышу про механизм исключений в C.

Comment: @Vlad ok, нужно проверить память. Сделаю. Что ещё? Даже с учётом отожранной памяти, приложение не способно сожрать так много чтобы вылететь. Да и это будет видно в Диспетчере задач.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша программа имеет неопрделенное поведение, потому что по крайней мере в этих циклах

```
for(j = 0; j < max_t; j++) for(i = 0; i < W[0]; i++) Pnew[i][j + 1] = Pold[0][j] * (1.0 / W[0]);
```

вы выходите за границу массива `Pnew` так как при `j` равном `max_t - 1` вы обращаетесь к элементу с индексом `max_t` в выражении `Pnew[i][j + 1]`.

Но в любом случае вам надо переписать код, так как это просто совершенно нечитабельно и бессмысленно, и я думаю, что имеются и другие явные баги.